# Getting a segment of a list

Tags: python

I'm looking for a pythonic way of geting all the strings between two specific strings in a list, excluding the two. It has to be based on the values of the strings, not on the index in the list. Example:

`["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5"]`

Segment between `"str1"` and `"str4"` would be `["str2", "str3"]`.

Comment: Do you always know the string names or are you fine with an index slice by numerical position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to index the values first and then slice:

```
print l[l.index("str1") + 1: l.index("str4")]
```